# Bootstrap CSS 4.0 navbar does not show menu on desktop browsers and always collapsed / shows hamburger menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap CSS. I took this code directly from Bootstrap 4.0 Beta page example (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).

In the Boostrap example page, this code works and shows navigations on desktop browsers, but when I use this code in my page, it does not show the navigations on the desktop browsers by default; it is showing the hamburger menu by default on any size browser.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I upgraded Chrome to the latest version and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you posted seems to run fine. Is there any more code you can add to your example?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: My Header:
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-4-beta/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-4-beta/bootstrap-grid.css">
    </head>
My Footer:
    <script src="/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-4-beta/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-4-beta/bootstrap-grid.min.js"></script>

Comment: Try using cdn's instead? like `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` and see if that works. If it does, then it may be problem with a file path you have.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, copy the contents of bootstrap.min.js from the previous version and it should be working.